# how can i make compile stage shorter in VCS (synopsys) after logic changed?

Tags: verilog, simulation, hardware, synopsys

if I changed few lines from a specific Verilog of design and now I want to recompile, can I compile just the related files or I need to compile the whole design again?
i'm using VCS tool by Synopsys.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the intermediate data base (like `simv/`), when you recompile the whole design, VCS will detect which file has changed, and only compile that. You can tell that by the output on terminal when VCS is running.